# pandoc or haskell fails with status code -15 on heroku

Tags: haskell, heroku, pandoc

I'm running pandoc on heroku by calling it from python, giving it a file I just created and expecting it to generate some output (convert markdown to html/latex).

When I run it locally it all works out, and I've managed to install pandoc on heroku, and when I run a bash on heroku I use pandoc and it is fine.

But when I call pandoc from python using `subprocess.check_call` it fails and exits with code -15.
Any idea what this code means? I think it is a Haskell code, not specific to pandoc.

Comment: Can you capture the stdout and stderr from the sub-process and see if it prints out any error messages?

Comment: I switched from `subprocess.check_call` to `subprocess.Popen(...)` and `subprocess.communicate()` but the heroku process hangs before printing the error message to the log, so I can't really print it out. Strangely it only happens when I run pandoc with the `--bibliography` option.

Comment: Also, If I run bash on heroku and try to call pandoc from there, it works for regular conversion but not with bibliography. Pandoc version is 1.9.4.2